# Two timeout methods

Tags: javascript, angular.js, comparative-review

I found there are two methods to code an `if`-`else` statement with a timeout function. Two of these scripts work fine, but which one of them is more preferable and why?

**Method One**

```
app.controller("filter", function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.expand = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            if ($scope.expandCollapse === "expand-up")
                $scope.expandCollapse = "expand-down";
            else
                $scope.expandCollapse = "expand-up";
        }, 1500); 
    };
});
```

**Method Two**

```
app.controller("filter", function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.expand = function() {
        if ($scope.expandCollapse === "expand-up")
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.expandCollapse = "expand-down";
            }, 1500);
        else
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.expandCollapse = "expand-up";
            }, 1500);
    };
});
```

Comment: I am not familiar with angular, but if `$scope.expand` can be called multiple times in a short time these two snippets will behave differently. The question is: What behaviour do *you* want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both pieces of code do different things. The first one schedules first, evaluates state second while the second one does the opposite, evaluating the state first, and schedule the timer second.

If this is part of animation code, where those strings are class names and the delay is intended to delay the animation, I suggest you move over this delay to CSS transitions instead. That way, it will all be just manipulating the value of `expandCollapse` without the timing element.

```
$scope.expand = function() {
  var isExpandUp = $scope.expandCollapse === "expand-up";
  $scope.expandCollapse = isExpandUp ? "expand-down" : "expand-up"; 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. What you mean is remove the $timeout from Angular and add the time delay in CSS right?